# Create a table without knowing its columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

How can I create a table without knowing in advance how many and what columns it exactly holds?

The idea is that I have a table DATA that has 3 columns : `ID`, `NAME`, and `VALUE`

What I need is a way to get multiple values depending on the value of `NAME` - I can't do it with simple `WHERE` or `JOIN` (because I'll need other values - with other `NAME` values - later on in my query).

Because of the way this table is constructed I want to `PIVOT` it in order to transform every distinct value of `NAME` into a column so it will be easier to get to it in my later search.

What I want now is to somehow save this to a temp table / variable so I can use it later on to join with the result of another query...

So example:

Columns:

```
CREATE TABLE MainTab
(
    id int, 
    nameMain varchar(max),
    notes varchar(max)
); 

CREATE TABLE SecondTab
(
    id int,
    id_mainTab, int,
    nameSecond varchar(max),
    notes varchar(max)
);

CREATE TABLE DATA
(
    id int,
    id_second int,
    name varchar(max),
    value varchar(max)
);
```

Now some example data from the table DATA:

```
|  id  | id_second_int |     name     |      value      |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |     5550      |   number     |   111115550     |
|  2   |     6154      |   address    | 1, First Avenue |
|  3   |     1784      |   supervisor |    John Smith   |
|  4   |     3467      |   function   |    Marketing    |
|  5   |     9999      |   start_date |    01/01/2000   |
::::
```

Now imagine that 'name' has A LOT of different values, and in one query I'll need to get a lot of different values depending on the value of 'name'...
That's why I pivot it so that number, address, supervisor, function, start_date, ... become colums. 
This I do dynamically because of the amount of possible columns - it would take me a while to write all of them in an 'IN' statement - and I don't want to have to remember to add it manually every time a new 'name' value gets added...
herefore I followed http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

the thing is know that I want the result of my execute(@query) to get stored in a tempTab / variable. I want to use it later on to join it with mainTab...
It would be nice if I could use @cols (which holds the values of DATA.name) but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

ADDITIONALLY:
If I use the not dynamic way (write down all the values manually after 'IN') I still need to create a column called status. Now in this column (so far it's NULL everywhere because that value doesn't exist in my unpivoted table) i want to have 'open' or 'closed', depending on the date (let's say i have start_date and end_date,

```
CASE end_date
WHEN end_date < GETDATE() THEN pivotTab.status = 'closed'
ELSE pivotTab.status = 'open'
```

Where can I put this statement? Let's say my main query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
(SELECT id_second, name, value, id FROM TABLE_DATA) src
PIVOT (max(value) FOR name IN id, number, address, supervisor, function, start_date, end_date, status) AS pivotTab
JOIN SecondTab ON SecondTab.id = pivotTab.id_second
JOIN MainTab ON MainTab.id = SecondTab.id_mainTab

WHERE pivotTab.status = 'closed';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can understand - you have some select statement and just need to "dump" its result to some temporary table. In this case you can use `select into` syntax like:

```
select .....
into #temp_table
from ....
```

This will create temporary table according to columns in select statement and populate it with data returned by select datatement.

See [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) for reference.

Comment: But i have to declare the temp_table as a table and then it wants to know the different columns - and I don't know how many or even which columns it will hold... That's why I want to do this using Dynamic SQL (but I'm a total noob in this area and still learning how to use it)

What I need mostly to complete my task at this point is information on where I can populate some columns in my created pivotTab (for example supply data for the column `status` depending on other values in the table)

Comment: @LisekKL *" i have to declare the temp_table as a table..."* - no, you don't. `select into` automatically will create it for you and populate with data returned by select statement. Or am I missed something from your real need?

Comment: ok sorry, the reason this didn't work for me is because I have read-only access to the database, so I can't create tables, functions or procedures...
Do you happen to have any idea on how to use the CASE statement (and where to put it) so I can populate data in my pivoted Table according to my needs?

Comment: @LisekKL well, in SQL server there are no special persmissions to create *temporary* table, so even if you have readonly access to database - you still can create *temporary* tables (not permanent ones) and use them in your further queries until your connection to SQL server is not closed. Probably it is all you need....